# Kivy Compiles to APK i cannot install

Tags: python, android, kivy, google-colaboratory, buildozer

I really would appreciate any form of help, I tried everything I knew and it didn't help. I have created an app in Kivy and I cannot compile it so it would work after trying several methods without a result I could finally compile an APK using google.colab however I cannot install it on any Android device.

Here is a test application which is very simple and is just there to try and compile it:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="test test test")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

I have used Buildozer and have relied on the steps shown in this toutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B__UOykI0Mo&t=303s
The only thing I have changed is libffi6 to libffi7 because it couldn't find libffi6.

I of course have tried to use an Linux Machine with buildozer however this method has simply created an Infinite Loop. At this point I'm begging for help, I haven't managed to compile a single app no matter what method and no matter how simple the App. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hello, but you should post some error logs of which made you know that it wasn't act as expected.

Comment: Thanks, however this is the problem there are no error logs, i get an fully compiled APK and when i try and "launch" it i just get the error message "apk wasnt installed"

Comment: The exact error message on Bluestacks:"Unfortunatly this app could not be installed. please verify the instalation file before trying again "

Comment: You may look for `logcat` for locating the error reason. Though I don't know how to find logcat in BlueStacks, but, if there exists a logcat, the reason why "APK wasn't installed" is there. Find it, post it.